# Alternative method for deriving $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$ for S.H.M

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to derive: $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$ for S.H.M.

I want to use the following method.

A particle is at position $x=x_1$ on the x-axis.

It starts with zero velocity. $x_1$ is therefore the amplitude of the motion.

Given: The particle experiences an acceleration $a=-\omega^2x$

I want to use calculus to show that the time $t$ it takes for the particle to go from $x=x_1$ to $x=0$ is $t=\frac{1}{4}\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$

My attempt:

$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}$$ $$dv=a\ dt=-\omega^2x\ \frac{dx}{v}$$ $$v\ dv=-\omega^2\ x\ dx$$  $$\int_0^{v_{max}}v\ dv=-\omega^2\ \int_{x_1}^0\ x\ dx$$ $$v_{max}^2=\omega^2\ x_{1}^2$$ $$v_{max}=\omega\ x_1$$

That's all I've got. I don't know how to bring the $t$ into the integral somehow.

Just to confirm I can derive this by simply considering the motion as a projection from circular motion. But I'd like to consider this approach.

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is S.H.M? Simple Harmonic Motion?

Comment: Try changing the limits of velocity $v$ from $0$ to the velocity $v'$ at any arbitrary location $x$, instead of using velocity at the equilibrium point ($v_{\rm max}$) as the other limit.

Comment: @FakeMod Thanks , but how do I then bring t into the derivation ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroLuque Yeah

Answer (score -1):

Start with the non-constant version of $s(t)= \frac{1}{2} a t^2$ which reads
\begin{align}
s(t) &= \int \int a(t) dt^2
= \int_0^t d\tau \int_0^\tau dt^\prime  a(t^\prime) 
\\
&= \int \int -\omega^{2} x(t) dt^2
= -\omega^{2} \int \int  x_0 \sin(\omega t) dt^2
= x_0 \sin(\omega t) 
\end{align}
(this equation is only valid up to the "equilibrium point".).
Now, what you are interested in is the time $t$ at which the oscillator travelled the distance $s(t)=x_0$. Hence, $\omega t = \pi/2$, or
$t = \pi/(2\omega)$

Comment: I haven't studied double integrals yet. Can it be done using single integrals ?

Comment: @Kantura: The acceleration is the second derivative of the distance w.r.t. time. Therefore, in general, one has to use two time integrals. However, since the "solution" $x(t) = x_0 sin(w t)$ is so simple, we already know the double integral: First we get $w^{-1} cos(wt)$, and then we get $-w^{-2} sin(wt)$. So, in the end we just use the "solution" $x(t) = x_0 sin(wt)$, and solve for $t$. To me this seams to go in a circle, but in your question you explicitly asked to start with $a=d^2s/dt^2$, and this is what leads to the double integral.